# Using Twilio. Send conference participant to "voicemail" recording if no one joins the conference in X amount of time

Tags: php, twilio

With Twilio I am trying to send or redirect a conference participant to a "leave a voicemail" option when no one joins the conference with them within a specific amount of time. I've tried using update announceUrl, but it will not allow me to use the record verb.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than using the `announceUrl` you should [update the call using the Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call?code-sample=code-create-a-call-2&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x) and redirect it to new TwiML that will record the voicemail.

Comment: That worked! Thank you

$call = $twilio->calls("xx")
               ->update(array(
                            "method" => "POST",
                            "url" => "http:// .. endpoint"
                        )
               );

Comment: Wonderful! Hope the rest of the app goes well.

Comment: link is not working can you please update that link

Comment: @philnash This is great, but how do we know the call/conference has been going for, say, 30 seconds? Is there a callback we can set somewhere?

Comment: @That1Guy There isn't a way to get a callback after 30 seconds of the conference being live, but you could [register to receive a statusCallback webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallback) when participants join the conference. The for the first one you can run a timer in your application that would update the call if no-one else joins and if the callback fires for another participant you can cancel the timer. Does that help?

Comment: @philnash Maybe - I'd have to kick off a separate thread, but I think I can swing it. I'll ask a proper question if my idea fails. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, either a separate thread or if you have a background job runner that could work too. Hope it goes ok.

Comment: @philnash could you please explain what the job would do? I don't really understand how the job would keep checking the time

Comment: It could either check using cron or a more fully featured example might be like [Laravel’s scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling). A job scheduler like that would make your jobs resilient to errors or restarts in the main process.

Comment: @philnash thanks for your answer. I ended up using a [delayed Job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#delayed-dispatching) so I could have more control over the time, since a cron command could only check every minute.

Comment: @CarlosMafla Glad that worked out for you!

Comment: @philnash I just posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973118/what-are-the-best-practices-with-twilio-devices-and-page-reloads maybe you can point me in the right direction? thanks!